# PHP ignoring if statements

Tags: php, html, forms, preg-match

I am having a very weird problem here, my if else statements just get ignored after I submit the form and all values entered or not entered goes through to the database.

Firstly, I pre populate all fields with info submitted during registration then users can edit and change their info - this works fine but I decided to add it as I don't know whether it might have a hand in this mystery error.

Here's my code to retrieve details, the variables holding retrieved values are echoed in their respective fields in the form.

```
<?php
include("connect.php");
$results = $conn->query("SELECT username, first_name,last_name,   email,phone,address FROM users WHERE email='$user_logged'");


while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    $u_name  = $row['username'];
    $f_name  = $row['first_name'];
    $l_name  = $row['last_name'];
    $email   = $row['email'];
    $phone   = $row['phone'];
    $address = $row['address'];
}

$results->free();

$conn->close();
?>
```

It's not checking for empty fields. Functions `test_input` and `preg_match` do not work alsko. The form just submits and database gets updated.

I have spent 2 days going through to look for where the error might be but I can't detect it.

```
<?php
$user_logged = $_SESSION['logged_in'];
if (isset($_POST['btnUpdate'])) {
    include("connect.php");
    $phoneErr   = $f_nameErr = $l_nameErr = "";
    $user_email = $first_name = $last_name = $phone_upadate = $address_updated = "";


    if (empty($_POST["fname"])) {
        $f_nameErr = "First Name is required";
    } else {
        $first_name = test_input($_POST["fname"]);
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $first_name)) {
            $f_nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["lname"])) {
        $l_nameErr = "Last Name is required";
    } else {
        $last_name = test_input($_POST["lname"]);
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $last_name)) {
            $l_nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
        $phoneErr = "Phone No is required";
    } else {
        $phone_upadate = test_input($_POST['phone']);
        if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]{0,18}$/", $phone_upadate)) {
            $phoneErr = "Only numbers and white space allowed";
        }

    }
    $user_email      = $_POST['email'];
    $address_updated = $_POST['txtaddress'];

    $results = $conn->query("UPDATE users SET   
        first_name='$first_name',last_name='$last_name', 
        email='$user_email',phone='$phone_upadate',
        address='$address_updated' 
        WHERE email='$user_logged'");

    if ($results) {

        header("Location: edit-info.php");
    } else {
        print 'Error : (' . $conn->errno . ') ' . $conn->error;
    }

}

function test_input($data)
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
?>
```

Here is my html code

```html
<form action="edit-info.php" method="POST">
   <?php $username_error="can't be changed"; ?>
   <p>Username</p>
   <p><input type="text" name="username" id="txtuser"  value="<?php echo  $u_name; ?>" readonly></input><span id="error"><?php echo $username_error?></span></p>
   <p>First Name</p>
   <p><input type="text" name="fname" id="txtuser"  value="<?php echo $f_name; ?>"></input><span id="error"><?php echo $f_nameErr;?></span></p>
   <p>Last Name</p>
   <p><input type="text" name="lname" id="txtuser"  value="<?php echo $l_name; ?>" ></input><span id="error"><?php echo $l_nameErr;?></span></p>
   <p>Email</p>
   <p> <input type="text" name="email" id="txtuser" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"  readonly></input><span id="error"><?php echo $f_nameErr;?></span></p>
   <p>Phone</p>
   <p><input type="text" name="phone" id="txtuser" value="<?php echo $phone; ?> " ></input></p>
   <span id="error"><?php echo $phoneErr;?></span>
   <p>Address</p>
   <p><textarea id="txtaddress" name="txtaddress" cols="40" rows="10" ><?php echo  $address; ?></textarea></p>
   <p><input type="submit" name="btnUpdate" value="UPDATE" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: It is hard to read without indentation, can you correct it please ? Also, did you try to add logs, to see where are executed lines, and is there anything in the php_error.log ?

Comment: Its my first time asking a question here , didn't quite get the indentation right , i have edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the values of $phoneErr, $f_nameErr, $l_nameErr before you proceed UPDATE like this

```
if(empty($phoneErr) && empty($f_nameErr) && empty($l_nameErr)){
   $results = $conn->query("UPDATE users SET      first_name='$first_name',last_name='$last_name', email='$user_email',phone='$phone_upadate',address='$address_updated' WHERE email='$user_logged'");
}
```

Because when you have any validation error in empty or preg_match you are updating these values. And without checking these $phoneErr, $f_nameErr, $l_nameErr variables you are proceeding to UPDATE

Answer (score 0):

You could try replacing

```
"/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/"
```

with

```
"/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/"
```

Notice we are replacing the `multiplication sign` with a `summation sign`.